# How can I block a referer (semalt) across my Apache server?

Tags: apache-2.4

[semalt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72107/semalt-ignores-robots-txt-does-their-own-form-actually-do-what-they-promise) is a pretty annoying company. I'd like to keep them off my servers (and out of my analytics).

[Here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-block-semaltcom-from-visiting-your-wordpress-website) it shows how to block them through `.htaccess` like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Via evil-spam-proxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer evil-spam-domain.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer evil-spam-keyword spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Via pinappleproxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer poker spammer=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spammer
```

I'd rather handle do this once and for all in my `/etc/apache`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html) files:

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. **Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a `<Directory>` block**, as it will have the same effect with better performance.